# How to get a specific value from a table in a view when you have conflicting names[Laravel]

Tags: php, laravel

Im making an application for a non-profit organisation for a school project and we are using laravel, the first time for me

I tried `{{$instructiekaart->instructiekaarten.name}}` but I get an error message when using this code

Controller

```
$instructiekaarten = DB::table('instructiekaarten')
->join('instructiekaart_set', 'instructiekaart_set.instructiekaart_id' ,'=', 'instructiekaarten.id')
->join('sets', 'sets.id' ,'=', 'instructiekaart_set.set_id')
->join('instructiekaart_stap', 'instructiekaart_stap.instructiekaart_id' ,'=', 'instructiekaarten.id')
->join('stappen', 'stappen.id' ,'=', 'instructiekaart_stap.stap_id')
->join('instructiekaart_user', 'instructiekaart_user.instructiekaart_id' ,'=', 'instructiekaarten.id')
->join('users', 'users.id' ,'=', 'instructiekaart_user.user_id')
->join('instructiekaart_niveau', 'instructiekaart_niveau.instructiekaart_id' ,'=', 'instructiekaarten.id')
->join('niveaus', 'niveaus.id' ,'=', 'instructiekaart_niveau.niveau_id')
->select('sets.name','instructiekaarten.name', 'stappen.name', 'niveaus.name')
->get();

return view('instructiekaarten.index')->with('instructiekaarten', $instructiekaarten);
```

View

```
@if(count($instructiekaarten) > 0)
        @foreach($instructiekaarten as $instructiekaart)
            <div class="card">
                <a href="/instructiekaarten">
                    <h5 class="card-header">{{$instructiekaart->instructiekaarten.name}}</h5>
                </a>
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <h5 class="card-title"></h5>
                        <p class="card-text"></p>
                    </div>
            </div>
        @endforeach
    @else
        <p>Geen instructiekaarten gevonden</p>
    @endif
```

This is the error message I get when using `{{$instructiekaart->instructiekaarten.name}}`

> Undefined property: stdClass::$instructiekaarten (View:
>   D:\wamp64\www\TZC\resources\views\instructiekaarten\index.blade.php)

Comment: Try dd($instructiekaart) and check what do you it's returning in "attributes" key?
Is it showing null ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try Giving alias

```
->select('sets.name AS sets_name','instructiekaarten.name AS instru_name', 'stappen.name AS stappen_name', 'niveaus.name AS niveaus_name')
```

& then

```
{{ $instructiekaart->instru_name }}
```